# Source & Target element is same when we do Drag & Drop in touch Devices using D3 (v3.4.12 )

Tags: svg, d3.js, nvd3.js, jquery-svg

I am doing Drop & Drop from touch device , ideally the source element & target element should not be the same.

Example I am dragging from polygon1 to polygon2 , so source should be Polygon1 & target or drop should be Polygon2 ,but in my case both are same(Polygon1).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/godsondabre/4gq519v6/23/).

[image: output]

```
var amatrix = [1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 500];
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('height', 500)
    .attr('width', 700);
var grp =   svg.append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "matrix(" + amatrix + ")");

grp.append('polygon')
                .attr('points', "50,50 150,50 150,150 50,150")
                .attr('stroke', '#f00')
                .attr('fill', 'red')
                .attr("id", 'Polygon_1');

grp.append('polygon')
                .attr('points', "200,200 300,200 300,300 200,300")
                .attr('stroke', '#f00')
                .attr('fill', 'blue')
                .attr("id", 'Polygon_2');
                
                
 grp.append('polygon')
                .attr('points', "350,350 450,350 450,450 350,450")
                .attr('stroke', '#f00')
                .attr('fill', 'green')
                .attr("id", 'Polygon_3');               
                
  svg.on("touchstart", function (event) {
                console.log(d3.event.srcElement.id);
                console.log('touchstart');
                d3.event.preventDefault();
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
                // event.stopPropagation();
            }, {
                passive: false
            }); 
      
  svg.on("touchend", function (event) {
                console.log(d3.event.srcElement.id);
                console.log('touchend');
                d3.event.preventDefault();
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
            }, {
                passive: false
            });
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use an up to date version of D3, *particularly* if you want to implement drag on a touch device. You can find a description of how D3 has been updated to work on touch devices in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@d3/multitouch).

Comment: Hello Mark,
Thanks for your response.

I have now updated my jsfiddle with latest d3 version.
but still i get the same element(even.srcElement) in Touch start & Touch end events.
means if i drag from polygon1 to polygon2  in touch start i should get polygon1 & touchend i should get polygon2.

https://jsfiddle.net/godsondabre/4gq519v6/36/